# How can I "re-run" the Amazon "public bucket check"?

Tags: amazon-s3

Amazon have lately been doing an exercise where they check your public S3 buckets and then raise a notification (and email) to an account to notify of these public S3 buckets.

It's quite useful (it has highlighted one bucket I had with inappropriate permissions) and I'd like to have it run on a regular basis.

But there's no documentation about this "public bucket check" process.

Does anyone know if there's any way I can access / control this functionality?
(I'd like to run it once a month or something).

Comment: Trusted Advisor does this if you have an appropriate support plan. If you're not paying support you don't get access to that check.

Comment: @Tim Ohhh, right.  If you add this I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trusted Advisor does this if you have an appropriate support plan, business and above I think. If you're not paying support you don't get access to that check.

Answer (score 1):

As per Tim's answer, this is a Trusted Adviser "security recommendation".
I couldn't find any public documentation of the individual Trusted Adviser recommendation, but when looking in the actual Trusted Adviser console, you can see this:

[image: trusted adviser s3 recommendation]

It appears a "business" level support plan is the minimum to get access to this recommendation.